HEIF / HEIC failed to view large files (200 MPx) Ubuntu 24.04
I have an issue with viewing  large HEIC files  from my phone s24 ultra.
50 MPx filex are showing, not so fast as jpeg, but it works fine, 200 MPx files cause blinking eog and  broken UI, program can be closed only by killing process (xkill or kill -9 pid)
I have added 3 files in 12 50 200 MPx and eog screenshot.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/e9mp4wb2akr578da8zyuu/ADT2ieu-DThdStTtCfSRIdc?rlkey=dsmru7cs6y3lbeduqsspqk9lp&dl=0
list of installled libraries:
➜  ~ apt list | grep heif  
heif-gdk-pixbuf/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
heif-gdk-pixbuf/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
heif-thumbnailer/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
heif-thumbnailer/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
kodi-imagedecoder-heif/noble 20.1.0+ds1-3build1 amd64
libheif-dev/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-dev/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-examples/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
libheif-examples/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-aomdec/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif-plugin-aomdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-aomenc/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
libheif-plugin-aomenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-dav1d/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-dav1d/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-ffmpegdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-ffmpegdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-j2kdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-j2kdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-j2kenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-j2kenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-jpegdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-jpegdec/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-jpegenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-jpegenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-libde265/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif-plugin-libde265/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-rav1e/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-svtenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-svtenc/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif-plugin-x265/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64
libheif-plugin-x265/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
libheif1/noble,now 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
libheif1/noble 1.17.6-1ubuntu4 i386
librust-libheif-rs-dev/noble 0.20.0-5 amd64
librust-libheif-sys-dev/noble 1.16.2-5 amd64

I also tried  gThumb and  have same issue, looks like problem not directly related to HEIC format, but to too huge file resolution.
my mashine
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
6.9.12-060912-generic
GNOME 46.0
Metacity


Sorry I do not see a Ubuntu related issue here. It would seem by your own comments that the files are just too high rez.

I have no change to check it on other distros and did not found similar issues anywhere. if it is not part of heic format reading or support, wha could be  the source  of issue? looks like not EOG,   how to localaze the issue to find a rigth place to repoart a bug?

Google search finds this. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/2076159
